# Launching fire and forget job via kotlin coroutines in Webflux application

Tags: kotlin, spring-webflux, kotlin-coroutines, reactive, fire-and-forget

I am rewriting very basic webflux application into kotlin coroutines for comparison purposes, meaning instead of reactor API, I am using suspend functions with Flows.

I am using webflux with postgres r2dbc running on the netty.

The code that is meant to be rewritten:

```kotlin
    override fun run(vararg args: String) {
        val sql = StreamUtils.copyToString(schema.inputStream, Charsets.UTF_8)

        val insertProducts = Flux.range(0, 1000)
            .map { Product(null, "product-$it", ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextDouble(10.0, 1000.0)) }
            .collectList()
            .flatMap { productRepository.saveAll(it).then() }


        template.databaseClient.sql(sql)
            .then()
            .then(insertProducts)
            .doFinally { logger.info { "Db data setup is finished." } }
            .subscribe()
    }
```

What I managed to implement:

```kotlin
    override fun run(vararg args: String) {
        val sqlInit = StreamUtils.copyToString(schema.inputStream, Charsets.UTF_8)

        runBlocking(Dispatchers.IO) {
            val products = mutableListOf<Product>()

            for (i in 1..1000) {
                Product(null, "product-$i", ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextDouble(10.0, 1000.0))
                    .also { products.add(it) }
            }
            val sqlExecutionFlow =
                template.databaseClient.sql(sqlInit)
                    .then()
                    .asFlow()

            val productsFlow = productRepository.saveAll(products) //CoroutineCrudRepository

            sqlExecutionFlow.onCompletion { logger.info { "Database initialized." } }.collect()
            productsFlow.onCompletion { logger.info { "Database filled with products." } }.collect()
        }
    }
```

It works, however I'd like to know if this is a good way how to do it.

It's a fire-and-forget job that should be triggered on the application startup.

Should I use runBlocking with IO dispatcher or without?
Should I rather use GlobalScope for it?

I read it is in general discouraged to use, but this seems like a valid case.

Thanks for any input.

Comment: While you do a `asFlow` I don't think it's real coroutines and so could not be considered a fair comparison of Reactor vs Coroutines

Comment: I'm just trying to rewrite everything that was written in reactor to kotlin coroutines approach, not for technical comparison only but also use experience (imperative vs declarative) 
The fair comparison (as you called it) comes with the general application flow (Request-Service-Response) 
I could still leave the db bootstrapping written in the reactor API though.
Just wanted to get some insights on different approaches, let's say one has no knowledge about reactor and still needs to work with Flow in user-independent tasks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should I use `runBlocking` with IO dispatcher or without?

Your code doesn't actually exercise the dispatcher at all, so you can safely remove that with no change in behavior. The dispatcher comes into action only when you launch more coroutines from `runBlocking`. The coroutine that starts automatically to execute the block of code you pass to `runBlocking` runs in the ad-hoc dispatcher it creates on the calling thread, which it occupies until completion.

> Should I rather use `GlobalScope` for it?

By this I think you mean "use `GlobalScope.launch`", and for your exercise I think that would be a step in the right direction.

If I compare your current solution to the original, I notice that the original is asynchronous in nature and `override fun run()` completes immediately, before the work is done. On the other hand, your usage of `runBlocking` results in synchronous operation.

If you replace `runBlocking` with `GlobalScope.launch`, you'll get the same asynchronous behavior.

One more point, which could be crucial in your phase of learning: coroutines do not need the declarative programming style to achieve their non-blocking behavior, and that is their main point. This gives you the freedom to write regular, procedural-looking code with `if` and `for`, and it will still be non-blocking — as long as you use suspendable API for IO.

This point relates to the initial one as well: as long as you use suspendable APIs, you never need `Dispatchers.IO`, which is there only as a workaround for the situations where you use a blocking API.

Comment: Thanks.
Yes the imperative approach was the main motivation to rewrite this.
Even if I still find the reactor API more elegant, and richer from the possibilities perspective.
For example when I wanted to repeatedly subscribe to get fresh results (metrics e.g) I could use mono.repeatWhen{ Flux.interval(duration) }

With flows I had to figure it out as its not out of the box solution like:
        return flow {
            while (true) {
                emit(getMetrics(...))
                delay(2.0.seconds)
            }
        }
Perhaps flow API will get richer by time.

Comment: OTOH, Flux is forced to introduce all these conveniences to the API since it's the only way. With coroutines you get to appreciate the added expressiveness of imperative code, like you wrote it --- just put a loop with a delay, and you get the same underlying async behavior as with the purpose-built higher-order function in Flux.